# How to generate unique hash values?

Tags: java, hash

I have 10M records. Each record has about 100 fields. When I read a record, I want to determine whether the record is a duplicate of another record I have read earlier. The criteria for duplicate check is based on 20 fields and checks for exact equality. I can take the new record and compare against all the previous records for each of the 20 fields.

Another approach I am considering is to hash the 20 fields into a single field and compare the hash with that of all the previous records. For this I need a hash function that will give me uniqueness. I am aware that there are functions like SHA512, SHA224, etc. Which hash function would be suitable for my use case?

Regards,
Yash

Comment: any hash function can give a collision, you should use hash set or smth similar

Comment: At a glance, SHA-256 or similar should do.  What are the 20 fields?  ints? Strings?  If Strings, avg length?

Comment: as good and strong as they can be, no hash function guarantees that unicity.
You can take the best there is, and combine it to another one with a complete different approach to narrow the chances of a collision, but it would still possible in theory.

Comment: There is no guarantee that hash values are unique (this is even [theoretically not possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). You can use hash values to do a quick check, but if you find two objects with the same hash you have to check them for equality field by field to see if they are really equal or not.

Comment: To commenters above: any hash function can create collisions, but if you know all the data you want to hash beforehand, you can construct a hash function that creates no collision _for that particular data set_, subject to some conditions.

Comment: Why 20 fields? no primary keys for the table?

Comment: If the goal is to set for exact equality, why not just, well, equality?

Comment: @fge: the only reason that I could think of is when _hashing + comparison of hashs_ is faster than _not hashing + comparison of original data_.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is called "[perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)". There's a classic approach in which you construct a hash function in two steps, i.e., by composing two hash functions. The construction is somewhat involved, but you might want to look into it.

Comment: You could also use a two-step approach: Use one hash function to check for duplicate records and then use another hash function or real comparison on all sets of detected duplicates to verify that they are real duplicates and no hash collision.

Comment: @FlorianLink ...which is how hashtables are typically implemented, i.e., it's fine to have _some_ collisions as long as you don't rely just on the equality of the hashs but also check the equality of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a similar problem before not on such a large scale but I will share my experience, hopefully it will help. It is a simple solution and since you posted this using the java tag I am assuming you know basics.
There will be 3 parts of the solution:

1. Joining of the 20 parameters into a long string to compute a simple hash using the hash method on java.lang.String class.
2. Removing prospective collisions by choosing an appropriate separator character such as a tab, newline, return or maybe even a unique long string which is unlikely to exist in the records. Example: "Unlikely String to exist in Stack Exchange answers 1234abcd". You can make it have integers, strings, your favorite quote, anything you want. Use the separator to join te 20 fields. This step requires having an understanding of the data you are seeing in those 20 fields say if it is all integers a simple character like 'a' will work fine.
3. Calculate and store the hash of the records one by one in a HashSet. This way for every new record you can check if you have seen it before and get rid of it or take whatever action you want to take on it.